# Case Statement in where clase in sql server 2014

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am creating a store procedure and in which am I stuck in a problem. I want to query two columns based on condition. If parameter is numeric then query to one column and if it is nonnumeric then query to other column. Following is the procedure.

```
   $
declare @result AS varchar(50)
DECLARE @peopleId AS varchar(50)
if('232332' NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%')
BEGIN
SET @result='Numeric'
PRINT @result
END
ELSE
BEGIN
set @result='nonNumeric'
print @result
END


select isnull(class.grade,'') as grade,ISNULL(class.room,'') as room,student.prefix as prefix,student.student_id as student_id,(person.first_name+' '+person.last_name) as name,
person.dob as dob,person.people_id as people_id,quit_on,
case when student.student_status='30' then 
N'พักการเรียน'
when student.student_status='31' then
N'น.ร.ไปเรียนโครงการฯ'
else ''
end
as quit_reason from school_student student
inner join people_person person on student.person_id=person.id
left join school_classroom_students classStudent on classStudent.student_id=student.id
left join school_classroom class on class.id =classStudent.classroom_id
where student.student_status in('30','31') and student.system_status = 'DC' and student.school_id=@schoolId 
AND case 
WHEN
@result='nonNumeric' then-- this should execure
 person.people_id=@peopleId
 else---- this should work
 person.first_name+' '+ person.last_name LIKE '%'+@peopleId+'%'
```

Please help me out on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would use use a separate variable?  You can do:

```
WHEN (person.people_id = try_convert(int, @peopleId) or
      try_convert(int, @peopleId) is null and 
 person.first_name + ' ' + person.last_name LIKE '%' + @peopleId + '%'
     )
```

I question why you are passing a value that is used for both a string and numeric comparison.  If I were using a variable, I would do:

```
declare @personid int;
declare @personname varchar(255);

if @peopleid not like '%[^0-9]%'
    set @personname = @peopleid;
else
    set @personid = convert(int, @peopleid);

where (personid = @personid or
       person.first_name + ' ' + person.last_name LIKE '%' + @personname + '%'
      )
```

The code just seems easier to follow.

Comment: Since the peopleId can contains numeric value and non numeric values. Because in the web site I have one text box in which user can put bot values.

Comment: So I user enter the Numeric values then @result='nonNumeric' then-- this should execure
 person.people_id=@peopleId   and if user enters non numeric than   else---- this should work
 person.first_name+' '+ person.last_name LIKE '%'+@peopleId+'%'
 should work

Answer (score -1):

Just do like that

```
DECLARE @IsNumeric INT = NULL
DECLARE @IsNotNumeric INT = NULL
DECLARE @peopleId Varchar(50)
SET @peopleId = '123'
IF ISNUMERIC(@peopleId) = 1
BEGIN
    SET @IsNumeric = 1
END
ELSE 
BEGIN
SET @IsNotNumeric =  1
END
```

IN WHERE Condition Just Check

```
AND (@IsNumeric IS NULL OR  CONVERT(VARCHAR(500),person.people_id)=@peopleId)
AND (@IsNotNumeric IS NULL OR person.first_name+' '+ person.last_name LIKE  '%'+@peopleId+'%')
```

Comment: I want to execute only one condition at a time. If user input numeric then first 1 should work else second condition should work.

Comment: Check the condition !! Only one condition is work at a time and you will get result perfectly.

Comment: @MuhammadAzim: it won't work because semantically all of the conditions in ANDs and ORs in a WHERE clause are checked. There is no short-circuiting in SQL. The first OR clause will fail if `@peopleId` is not numeric, regardless of the status of the `@IsNumeric` variable.

Comment: @siride, thanks for your concern.  I forget to cast the column value. I update my answer.  Now this will be work fine. Note : The length of cast must be the length of input parameter.

Answer (score -1):

Since SQL Server doesn't treat results of CASE expressions as booleans, you have to add an extra comparison. The way to do that is like this:

```
WHERE 1 = CASE WHEN x THEN 1 WHEN y THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```

Conditions which result in rows being included in the result must evaluate to 1, and conditions which don't, must evaluate to something other than 1 (like 0). So the whole CASE expression returns either 0 or 1, and that is compared to 1.

In your code, it would look like this:

```
AND 1 = case
WHEN
@result='nonNumeric' then case when person.person_id = @peopleId then 1 else 0 end
 else when person.first_name+' '+person.last_name LIKE '%'+@peopleId+'%' then 1 else 0 end
end
```

I added the END.

Comment: I have tried this but getting the syntax error on [like] and [when] cases

Comment: @VirenderThakur: you probably typed it in wrong or included it in the wrong part of your WHERE clause. Without your full code, I can only make a very unlikely guess as to what the problem actually is.